# nodejs reconnect net connection

Tags: node.js

I have a net client connection to a socket (using net.createConnection(port,host). this works fine.

However, sometimes there is the possibility of the server dropping the connection, and I would like the net connection to automatically reconnect when the server is back up and running

I can trap the on('end') event to catch the initial disconnect, and try to reconnect.

However,how can I check to see if the client has connected, because I want to retry every n milliseconds on a backoff strategy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `end` handler, set a timeout that will retry the connection, and set a one time `connect` handler that will cancel the timeout.

Comment: I think that I got that far, but how do I detect if a connect attempt failed, in order to retry again ?

Comment: If your connect attempt succeeded, then your `connect` handler will have cancelled the timeout. That means that if your timeout code runs at all, the connect attempt either failed or is still in progress. If you set the timeout value appropriately (long enough that if the attempt hasn't succeeded by then, it's not likely to succeed), you can simply assume that the attempt failed and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that has worked for me.

```
if ( !client.readable )
    client.connect(PORT,HOST);
else
    logger.debug('Attempt to reconnect on an active connection. Ignored.');
```

The use of client.readable will return a value -- immediately -- if the connection is alive. If not, then simply reconnect. Using client.writable fails.

I found this approach more robust as sometimes the END or CLOSE events don't happen (e.g.: VPN shutdown, crash or power failure on server side, etc)